# Mimic $_GET in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get query string values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)
>   [Parse query string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript)
>   [Storing php $_GET variable in a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311961/storing-php-get-variable-in-a-javascript-variable)

How can I mimic `$_GET` in JavaScript, and display the value of the `$_GET`, so: how can I do this kind of thing in JavaScript:

```
if($_GET['id'] == 1)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: You actually want to [parse the query string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2090551/112968)

Answer (score 0):

Could always use `document.location.href` to do this.

Something like:

```
var url = document.location.href, get;
get = url.split('?');
get = get.split('&');
```

Which will leave you with an array of the `$_GET` variables.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you want:

1. [Parse the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2090551/112968), as mentioned by knittl
2. Store the $_GET contents in the user's session on the server side, and use an AJAX request to retrieve the data from the session.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the URL parameters I'd suggest using a regular expression and/or jQuery, a quick example:

```
$.getUrlParameters = function(name, url) {
    var theURL = url || window.location.href;
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(theURL);
    if (!results) { return 0; }
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

See this similar topic:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript/901144#901144)