# PHP $_GET but with Javascript

Tags: javascript, get

I am able to get data from a URL with the following structure -

```
http://mydomain.com/test.php?word=hello
```

Using PHP I would use the following

```
$word = $_GET["word"];
```

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to achieve the same thing but using `JavaScript`?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP GET request in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311961/storing-php-get-variable-in-a-javascript-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Source: [Get URL Parameters Using Javascript](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can get these values using `window.location.search`. You can either roll your own code to parse this or use something like the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript).